# Javascript removing decimals in knockout binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've seen there are quite a few questions about decimal precision and display in Javascript. the thing is that I came to a solution that I thought it was gonna be enough for me'

The key thing is that I'm trying to parse to a string to round and then back to numbers using expressions like this.

```
return parseFloat(num.toFixed(2));
```

But there are some cases that it doesn't work as expected. To be honest I'm not sure if it has to do with the way I'm using ko or the javascript code for parsing I put in place. But let's say that in the below fiddle you type 14.385 in the upper text box, both fields will be properly rounded and will display the correct number of decimals, but without deleting the number you add 3333 (that means 14.393333) and the upper one won't be rounded. That's just an example because there are some strange behaviours.

Yo can see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/RTexF/

Thanks

Edit. I add the code as per judgeja indication (I didn't understand the reason to ask for a code when you link fiddle, I see the point now)

The script

```
var decimalValue = 0.25;

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.submittedValue = ko.observable(decimalValue);

    self.percentage = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            alert('read');
            if (isNaN(parseFloat(self.submittedValue())))
                return '';

            var num = self.submittedValue() * 100;
            return parseFloat(num.toFixed(2));

        },
        write: function(value) {
            alert('write');
            value = isNaN(value) ? '' : parseFloat((value / 100).toFixed(4));
            self.submittedValue(value);
        },
        owner: self
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And the html

```
<p><input data-bind="value:percentage"></input></p>
<p><input data-bind="value:submittedValue"></input></p>
```

EDIT:

Know that it's an old one but I wanted to note that adding this to the write method

```
self.percentage.notifySubscribers(value);
```

it fixes the issue (ideally we could check against the current value and just notifiy if it actually changes)

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RTexF/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/RTexF/2/

Comment: You should post the jsfiddle code in your question as jsfiddle is known to go down from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help you to think about this if you put an `alert("read")` in the *read:* and an `alert("write")` in the *write:* and then run your example again.

When you change the top box the first time the bottom box is written to through the **write** and then the top box is re-computed as the `submittedValue` observable has changed and you'll see the **read** for percentage being hit.

Next time you edit the top box the **write** will be hit again as we're changing the value, which makes sense, but since the `submittedValue` isn't changed, then the **read** won't happen again as the observable it depends upon won't have changed.